# sending email from laravel using another "from" header

Tags: php, laravel

blahblahHi does anyone know how to set the FROM part of an email. In the config for email you can set it there but I want to use an `noreply@whatever.com` something like this e.g. the code below doesn't work tho

```
Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), 'username' => $username), function($message) use ($user) {
    $message->from('noreply@whatever.com', 'Activate Account');
    $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Activate your account');
});
```

I just want to be able to use the `noreplay@whatever.com` instead of using the configuration setting in the `mail.php`

when I use `$message->from('noreply@whatever.com', 'Activate Account');` it still shows my gmail account instead of `noreply@whatever.com`

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 587,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' => 'admin@blahblah.com', 'name' => 'SuperStore'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => 'blahblah@gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => '**********',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Comment: Are you using swift mailer ? or only SMTP ?

Comment: I think I'm using smtp. I've changed the settings in the mail.php file in config. I used the default mail option

Comment: `noreplay@whatever.com` and `noreply@whatever.com` is that a type ? What is your current headers (from) that you receive ?

Comment: I believe you have this in your mail.php in the config 'from' => array('address' => 'noreply@whatever.com', 'name' => 'Activate Account'), Isn't it ?

Comment: it just uses my email account on gmail as the from section myemail@gmail.com which is in my setting in my mail.php file

Comment: Ah!!! You will have the sender that is defined in your `mail.php`

Comment: If you have your gmail address in your `mail.php` then it will be your `sender`

Comment: Check my code again i've added my mail.php class for you to have a look at

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80962/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-kdm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot trigger email with cross-domain

i.e.,

If you have smtp configured with your gmail and you cannot send mail with some other domains.

This is something related to [Email Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing) which is not allowed.

You can send emails only for the domain what you have configured in your `mail.php`.

Doc about [Laravel Mail Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail)

[Full Transcript of the Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/80962) which might help for future Readers